# Rails do not parse my HTTP query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, curl

I issued a HTTP request using CURL.

```
curl -X GET  \
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user_api/35/edit?old_password=aa&new_password=bb&password_confirmation=cc
```

My rails server only recognise the first  parameter

```
Started GET "/api/v1/user_api/35/edit?old_password=aa" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-01 14:12:52 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::UserApiController#edit as */*
Parameters: {"old_password"=>"aa", "id"=>35}
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

-------------------------------------Edit-----------------------------------------------------

WARNING! This is a very bad wild insane example of handling password reset.

The question is only aimed for topic of curl and query parsing issues.

Thank you for all your comments

Comment: Don't use GET to pass or change passwords. It would put it into the URL and the history of a browser and the server log. Use a POST method instead.

Comment: @theTinMan Hi, thank you for the comment. If this is a api designed for mobile apps, is POST method still more preferable than GET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any idea what is wrong here?

You're passing passwords in plain text in the query string.

How about you start by not doing that?

---

Also, you need to put your URL in quotes as the `&` otherwise needs to escaped

```
curl -X GET  \
"http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user_api/35/edit?old_password=aa&new_password=bb&password_confirmation=cc"
```

But really, please don't use `GET` to send password data

Comment: It is an api exposed to mobile apps. I guess it does not matter whether it is GET or POST as it will not be logged by any browser. Encryption is quite an advanced topic to me now, but sure, I will look into that soon

Comment: As for the solution, I will test that as soon as I get my hands on my development machine, thank you very much.

Comment: Haha, I don't mean to laugh, but the fact that it's designed for "mobile apps" doesn't reduce the security threat at all.

Comment: Because I think only encryption can stop hackers, not GET or POST. Unencrypted POST body make any difference?  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Obviously you want to use SSL, but it's still bad form to be using `GET` when in updates. That's *exactly* what POST is for. You may not be REST-ful, but try not to wildly violate those principles.